# wxPython: Expanding a RowColSizer in a ScrolledPane in a Notebook

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

[Pastebin code here](http://pastebin.com/qjcT0XAb) - ready to run

I have a RowColSizer inside a ScrolledPanel, inside a Notebook; the scrolledpanel expands fine horizontally, but won't update vertically. What am I doing wrong?

When running the example, click the Texture tab, and you will see a block of colour getting cut off; that's supposed to be a 256x256 square. If you click +Variant, you can add more blocks horizontally, and the scrollbars expand.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, setting the proportion to 1 on line 71 fixes the issue... somewhat. Not ideal though - I thought wx.EXPAND was supposed to take care of that.